# Powershell Get-Content Mutex Can't Find Path

Tags: powershell

Big picture is to update a json file with the status from multiple scripts which should take milliseconds for each update and total about 10 updates per script but could happen at virtually same time.

I have a function that I am trying to update a status.json file from multiple Scheduled Tasks each executed from Seperate Scheduled Task > Batch File > PowerShell.  I use the Mutex to get a lock so they don't fight over the file.

My first "thread" seems to work fine, it updates the file no problems and continues and updates over and over.  The other "threads" return `Cannot find path 'D:\status.json' because it does not exist.` Error. It does not make sense why Get-Content fails as the first "thread" works so file must exist.

It could be a false Error and maybe it is really just locked. How would I test if locked and why wouldn't it unlock, I have tried sleeping for various amounts and the error still happens.

Anyone have any ideas, thoughts, improvements?

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  3053
```

```
Function UpdateStatus ([String]$db,[String]$start,[String]$end,[String]$status)
{
    $InFile = "D:\status.json"

    $mtx = New-Object System.Threading.Mutex($false, "Global\LogMutex")
    [void]$mtx.WaitOne()

    Try
    {
        $stsJSON = Get-Content $InFile -Encoding UTF8 -ErrorAction Stop | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

        $stsJSON | ForEach-Object `
        {
            If ($_.DatabaseName -eq $db)
            {
                If ($start -ne $null -and $start -ne "")
                {
                    $_.Start = $start
                }

                If ($end -ne $null -and $end -ne "")
                {
                    $_.End = $end
                }

                If ($status -ne $null -and $status -ne "")
                {
                    $_.Status = $status
                }
            }
        }

        $stsJSON | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content $InFile -Encoding UTF8
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Host "Could not update Status. `r`n"
        Write-Host "`r`n"
        Write-Host "$_`r`n" -ForegroundColor Red
        Start-Sleep 1
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    [void]$mtx.ReleaseMutex()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I can't be sure this above code will work 100%, I believe I was testing incorrectly and abandoned this approach for a different option as I received a new requirement.  The new requirement today, was that the instances were going to be separated on different servers and I don't think Mutex works over UNC.  I have opted to try a file.lock approach.